# Injecting a resource into an abstract class

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection

I have an abstract class, Shape, and I have a Canvas object that the Shape uses to set its position. I need to make sure that all Shapes have a Canvas object, preferably a Canvas object that is the same one across all shapes.

I have thought of a couple of options:

- Add a canvas parameter to the Shape constructors (there are many)
- Having some sort of place where the abstract Shape gets its Canvas (when a default is required)
- Make all my shape construction go through a factory of some sort.

Which one is the best?

I am using C# / .NET 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Dependency Injection (DI) the best *default* pattern is **Constructor Injection** (your first option) because it can easily be implemented to ensure your Shapes' invariants.

Just add a Guard Clause to your Shape ctor like this:

```
private readonly Canvas canvas;

protected Shape(Canvas canvas)
{
    if(canvas == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("canvas");
    }
    this.canvas = canvas;
}
```

This ensures that the canvas field is *always* available and *never* null.

You can achieve this property in other ways, but Constructo Injection is by far the simplest way to ensure invariants, so I always choose that as my default DI strategy unless I have other needs.

Answer (score 0):

What about having ICanvas public property that gets injected by di framework? 
If you really have a lot of classes implementing Shape, that means a lot of constructors with Canvas parameter, for property you declare it once in Shape and use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought the other way around. I mean having a canvas object and then adding shapes object to it. This way all your shapes objects have a common reference point which is Canvas. A canvas object having a collection of shapes.. This way you can perform common operations to shapes such as resize all the shapes when canvas resizes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar idea as S M Kamran: You can have a `Canvas` property in your `Shape` class to indicate the canvas to which that shape belongs to, and a `Shapes` collection in your `Canvas` class to hold a collection of shapes:

Here's a quick example:

```
interface ICanvas
{
    // It's a good thing to use an interface
    // in this phase. It will allow you greater
    // freedom later.
}

class Canvas : ICanvas
{
    private Shape.ShapeCollection _shapes;
    public Collection<Shape> Shapes
    {
        get { return _shapes; }
    }

    public Canvas()
    {
        _shapes = new Shape.ShapeCollection(this);
    }
}

class Shape
{
    public class ShapeCollection : Collection<Shape>
    {
        private readonly ICanvas _parent;
        public ShapeCollection(ICanvas parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
        }

        protected override void InsertItem(int index, Shape item)
        {
            item._canvas = _parent;
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
        }

        protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
        {
            this[index]._canvas = null;
            base.RemoveItem(index);
        }

        protected override void SetItem(int index, Shape item)
        {
            RemoveAt(index);
            InsertItem(index, item);
        }

        protected override void ClearItems()
        {
            while (this.Count != 0)
                this.RemoveAt(this.Count - 1);
        }
    }

    private ICanvas _canvas;
    public ICanvas Canvas
    {
        get { return _canvas; }
    }
}
```

By adding a shape to a canvas, `Shape.Canvas` property will be updated automatically:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
Shape circle = new Shape();

canvas.Shapes.Add(circle);
```

Note that `ShapeCollection` is a nested class inside `Shape`, because it's the only way to set the private `_canvas` property.

Generic collections (like `Collection<Shape>`) are often used for similar problems, because you can override their `InsertItem`/`RemoveItem` properties to add custom functionality when the collection is being changed.

You can also create an "Empty/Default Canvas" singleton, and use it instead of null when shape is not assigned to a real canvas (just to avoid checking if `Shape.Canvas` is null every time).